# How to auto scroll horizontally to a specific div on load of a component using Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

When ever user will login it will be redirected to a component where the auto scroll will move to a particular div in html.

Comment: You can use third-party package to achieve this something like : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-page-scroll

Comment: What you have tried to achieve this functionality till now.